# Wordpress nested shortcode content

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I would like to use the following shortcodes:

```
[section]
<h1>Section body content</h1>
[section_footer]<p>Section footer content</p>[/section_footer]
[/section]
```

So, I have added the following shortcode callbacks:

```
function sec_cb ($att, $content = null) {
// ...
return 
'
<section>
<div class="sec-body">
'.strip_shortcodes($content).'
</div>
'.do_shortcode($content).'
</section>
';
}

function sec_footer_cb ($atts, $content = null) {
return 
'
<div class="sec-footer">
'.$content.'
</div>
';
}
add_shortcode('section', 'sec_cb');
add_shortcode('section_footer', 'sec_footer_cb');
```

But the output is:

```
<section>
 <div class="sec-body">
  <h1>Section body content</h1>
 </div>
 <h1>Section body content</h1>
 <div class="sec-footer">
  <p>Section footer content</p>
 </div>
</section>
```

How can I fix it and print in footer only footer shortcode content ?

Comment: Maybe you have registered both function on the same hook `do_shortcode`. Please Update the Post and set how/where you call the functions `sec_cb` and `sec_footer_cb`.

Comment: Hi @JoseCarlosRamosCarmenates, please check the update

Comment: Right now you are print in the footer the correct content see: `<div <p>Section footer content</p></div>` you don't have de section content like `<h1>Section body content</h1>` Please what's the output needed?

Answer (score 0):

Please try add `ob_start()` and `ob_get_contents()` and `ob_end_clean()`, I adjust your code with that. Try and let me know if it work.

```
function sec_cb ($att, $content = null) {
    // ...
    ob_start();
    echo '<section>
            <div class="sec-body">
               '.strip_shortcodes($content).'
            </div>
            '.do_shortcode($content).'
          </section>';
    $eval_result = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $eval_result;
}

function sec_footer_cb ($atts, $content = null) { 
    ob_start();
    echo '<div class="sec-footer">
            '.$content.'
        </div>';
    $eval_result = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $eval_result;
}

add_shortcode('section', 'sec_cb');
add_shortcode('section_footer', 'sec_footer_cb');
```

Comment: Thanks @JoseCarlosRamosCarmenates, but the output is exactly the same :(

Comment: @DDE What's the output expected?